# Redux: access to store outside of the component

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm trying to get access to the store from outside of the component and subscribe it for store changes. I have separate file which I'm using to make an API call.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import store from '../store/store'

const currentWeatherApi = {
    key: "",
    base: "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/"
  }

  const API = () => {
    
    const inputValue = useSelector(state => state.inputValue);
    store.subscribe(() => {
      console.log(inputValue)
    })

    if(inputValue) {
      fetch(`${currentWeatherApi.base}weather?q=rzeszow&units=metric&APPID=${currentWeatherApi.key}`)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(result => {
        const temp = (Math.floor(result.main.temp));
        const tempMin = result.main.temp_min
        const tempMax = result.main.temp_max;
        const location = result.name;
        const sunrise = new Date(result.sys.sunrise * 1000).toISOString().substr(11, 8);
        const sunset = new Date(result.sys.sunset * 1000).toISOString().substr(11, 8);
        const country = result.sys.country;
        const wind = result.wind.speed;
        const pressure = result.main.pressure;
        const sky = result.weather[0].main;
      })
    }

export default API;
```

When I try to console.log anything, nothing happens, like it's not even read. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Not sure why you're using `useSelector` here. That's a hook that gets values from React context. to get store values use `store.getState()`

Comment: `useSelector` is a hook from the react-redux package, it is aimed to be used to get the state.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`API` isn't a React component so the `useSelector` hook won't work. You can import the store and call [getState](https://redux.js.org/api/store#getstate) on it to get the current state's value.

> **getState()**
>
> Returns the current state tree of your application. It is equal to the
> last value returned by the store's reducer.
>
> **Returns**
>
> (any): The current state tree of your application.

```
const API = () => {
  const state = store.getState();

  if(state.searchingBar.inputValue) {
    fetch(`${currentWeatherApi.base}weather?q=rzeszow&units=metric&APPID=${currentWeatherApi.key}`)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(result => {
        ....
      })
  }
}
```

## Edit for Demo

[image: Edit redux-access-to-store-outside-of-the-component]

Demo code:

```
const initialState = {
  inputValue: ""
};

const slice = createSlice({
  initialState,
  name: "searchingBar",
  reducers: {
    updateValue: (state, action) => {
      state.inputValue = action.payload;
    }
  }
});

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  searchingBar: slice.reducer
});

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: rootReducer
});

const fetch = (url, options) => {
  console.log("fetch", { url });
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    const response = {
      json: async () => "boom"
    };
    return resolve(response);
  });
};

const currentWeatherApi = {
  base: "base",
  key: "key"
};

const API = () => {
  const state = store.getState();

  console.log(JSON.stringify(state));

  if (state.searchingBar.inputValue) {
    fetch(
      `${currentWeatherApi.base}weather?q=rzeszow&units=metric&APPID=${currentWeatherApi.key}`
    )
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((result) => {
        console.log("Result", result);
        store.dispatch(slice.actions.updateValue(""));
      });
  }
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <div className="App">
        <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
        <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>

        <button type="button" onClick={API}>
          Call API
        </button>
        <button
          type="button"
          onClick={() => store.dispatch(slice.actions.updateValue("test"))}
        >
          Update State
        </button>
      </div>
    </Provider>
  );
}
```

Comment: Tryed to do this earlier. My Redux state looks like this `searchingBar: {inputValue: ''},`, when I try to `inputValue = store.getState()` and then console.log this, still nothing happens.

Comment: @AlbertKarkut Can you share how you setup and export `store`? Are you trying to pass input from a user to this weather API call? Why not access the state in the component making the call and pass the input as an argument? Can you also update your question to show us how you are calling `API`?

Comment: My `store` looks like this: 
`import { applyMiddleware, createStore } from 'redux';
import { composeWithDevTools } from 'redux-devtools-extension'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import apiReducer from '../duck/reducer'

const store = createStore(apiReducer, composeWithDevTools())

export default store;`

Comment: @AlbertKarkut what do you mean by nothing happens when you console log. are you expecting that that console logging will somehow trigger a store update? what is actually dispatching actions to your store to trigger the subcription callback? also `store.getState().searchingBar.inputValue` ?

Comment: @DrewReese, I used to trigger an API call using a condition, If it returns true then APi was called. That's how I wanted to do it now as well. I wanted to pass an inputValue from the store and If it returns true, API would fetch. I guess it's not the right way to do this in redux?

Comment: @azium, my bad, i thought that `store.subscribe()` is called whenever redux state is changed and after that I wanted to console.log my inputValue.

Comment: the callback you pass to `store.subscribe(...callback here...)` gets called when the store is updated. if you want to get the latest state you need to put `store.getState()` INSIDE your subscribe callback. `subscribe` itself is only called once

Comment: @AlbertKarkut IMO the component should be connected to the store (via `useSelector`) and check the state value and conditionally call `API` and pass any values it needs on to the `fetch` request, though in your snippet it doesn't appear exists a dependency. The above with getting the store value in the utility function seems like it would accomplish nearly the same thing. I don't think you need to subscribe to the store here though, you just want the latest value, on-demand when `API` is called.

Comment: Sorry, I lost myself a bit. I'll try to do this like u said before for now. Changed it to this `const state = store.getState();    if(state.searchingBar.inputValue) { fetch, console.log }` but nothing triggers. So, I can use useSelector even If my component is not wrapped with a provider?

Comment: @AlbertKarkut No, if you use the `useSelector` hook then that component **must** be rendered within a redux provider. This is usually the case though when the redux provider is wrapping your entire application. The `API` function isn't a component so it can't use React hooks, but it *can* still access the store's value. You still haven't explained what "but nothing happens" means. Are you calling `API` somewhere to make "something happen"?

Comment: @DrewReese you right. No, I don't call for it anywhere. I just thought that If `state.searchingBar.inputValue` returns true, then API will fetch, but it doesn't.

Comment: I understand that my way to do it is wrong, so how should I do it?

Comment: @AlbertKarkut It would be done very similar to how I originally posted it in my answer. I've updated my answer to include a link to a working codesandbox and included the demo code.